# Using Ansible to Install Jenkins Plugins tells me the crumb value is invalid

Tags: jenkins, plugins, vagrant, ansible

**TL;DR**

Jenkins is telling me I am passing an invalid crumb value when installing plugins from an Ansible script

**Details**

I have Jenkins 2.32.2 running in a Docker container, using the official Docker container.

I have installed it to a Vagrant VM, and am attempting to configure the plugins using Ansible.

I am iterating through a list of plugins using the following task

```
- name: Install plugins
  include: install_plugin.yml
  with_items: "{{ plugins }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: plugin_name
  tags: [jenkins]
```

with the following list defined in the defaults/main.yml file

```
plugins:
  - git
  - template-project
  - pipeline
  - docker-workflow
  - template-project
  - config-file-provider
  - bitbucket
  - disk-usage
  - greenballs
  - jacoco
  - slack
  - sonar
```

Below is the definition of install_plugin.yml which is called from the main.yml file

```
---
- name: Get Jenkins crumb
  uri:
    user: admin
    password: "{{ jenkins_admin_password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    url: "http://{{ ansible_hostname }}:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json"
    return_content: yes
  register: crumb_token
  until: crumb_token.content.find('Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready') == -1
  retries: 10
  delay: 5
  tags: [jenkins]

- name: Plugins are installed
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ ansible_host }}:8080/pluginManager/installNecessaryPlugins"
    method: POST
    user: admin
    password: "{{ jenkins_admin_password }}"
    body: '<jenkins><install plugin="{{ plugin_name }}@latest" /></jenkins>'
    headers:
      Content-Type: "text/xml"
      Jenkins-Crumb: "{{ crumb_token.json.crumb }}"
    creates: "{{ jenkins_home }}/plugins/{{ plugin_name }}"
  register: plugins_result
  tags: [jenkins]

- wait_for:
    path: "{{ jenkins_home }}/plugins/{{ plugin_name }}"
  tags: [jenkins]
```

When I attempt to emulate this using curl from the command line, I get the expected results using the following 2 commands, it works successfully

```
~/Projects/ci> curl --user admin:admin cluster01:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json
{"_class":"hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer","crumb":"646966a811fe84bdc5dc00a0de942b80","crumbRequestField":"Jenkins-Crumb"}%

~/Projects/ci> curl -X POST --user admin:admin -d '<jenkins><install plugin="git@latest" /></jenkins>'  --header 'Jenkins-Crumb: 646966a811fe84bdc5dc00a0de942b80' --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' http://cluster01:8080/pluginManager/installNecessaryPlugins
```

But when I run the Ansible playbook, I get the following error

```
status code was not [200]: HTTP Error 403: No valid crumb was included in the request
```

Here is the log output from -vvvv for this step

```
TASK [jenkins : Install plugins] ***********************************************
task path: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/main.yml:56
included: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml for cluster01
included: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml for cluster01
included: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml for cluster01
included: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml for cluster01
included: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml for cluster01
included: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml for cluster01
included: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml for cluster01
included: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml for cluster01
included: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml for cluster01
included: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml for cluster01
included: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml for cluster01

TASK [jenkins : Get Jenkins crumb] *********************************************
task path: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml:2
Using module file /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.2.0.0_2/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/network/basics/uri.py
<cluster01> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<cluster01> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile=".vagrant/machines/cluster01/virtualbox/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/chris/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r cluster01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.3-32614286575555 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1486148016.3-32614286575555="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.3-32614286575555 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<cluster01> PUT /var/folders/g5/h48p994d3qn7d9_nz7xv2lvh0000gn/T/tmprL_Pye TO /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.3-32614286575555/uri.py
<cluster01> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile=".vagrant/machines/cluster01/virtualbox/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/chris/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[cluster01]'
<cluster01> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<cluster01> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile=".vagrant/machines/cluster01/virtualbox/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/chris/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r cluster01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.3-32614286575555/ /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.3-32614286575555/uri.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<cluster01> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<cluster01> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile=".vagrant/machines/cluster01/virtualbox/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/chris/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt cluster01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-vzqwuvcglpsfrrzkvwdcupjtukijcwvl; /usr/bin/python /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.3-32614286575555/uri.py; rm -rf "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.3-32614286575555/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
ok: [cluster01] => {
    "attempts": 1, 
    "changed": false, 
    "connection": "close", 
    "content": "{\"_class\":\"hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer\",\"crumb\":\"ad67abc734af7eae279df5c68098a29e\",\"crumbRequestField\":\"Jenkins-Crumb\"}", 
    "content_type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8", 
    "date": "Fri, 03 Feb 2017 18:53:36 GMT", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "backup": null, 
            "body": null, 
            "body_format": "raw", 
            "content": null, 
            "creates": null, 
            "delimiter": null, 
            "dest": null, 
            "directory_mode": null, 
            "follow": false, 
            "follow_redirects": "safe", 
            "force": false, 
            "force_basic_auth": true, 
            "group": null, 
            "headers": {
                "Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
            }, 
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget", 
            "method": "GET", 
            "mode": null, 
            "owner": null, 
            "password": "admin", 
            "regexp": null, 
            "remote_src": null, 
            "removes": null, 
            "return_content": true, 
            "selevel": null, 
            "serole": null, 
            "setype": null, 
            "seuser": null, 
            "src": null, 
            "status_code": [
                200
            ], 
            "timeout": 30, 
            "unsafe_writes": null, 
            "url": "http://cluster01:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json", 
            "url_password": "admin", 
            "url_username": "admin", 
            "use_proxy": true, 
            "user": "admin", 
            "validate_certs": true
        }, 
        "module_name": "uri"
    }, 
    "json": {
        "_class": "hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer", 
        "crumb": "ad67abc734af7eae279df5c68098a29e", 
        "crumbRequestField": "Jenkins-Crumb"
    }, 
    "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)", 
    "redirected": false, 
    "server": "Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)", 
    "status": 200, 
    "url": "http://cluster01:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json", 
    "x_content_type_options": "nosniff", 
    "x_jenkins": "2.32.2", 
    "x_jenkins_session": "3abb7e45"
}

TASK [jenkins : Plugins are installed] *****************************************
task path: /Users/chris/Projects/ci/roles/jenkins/tasks/install_plugin.yml:15
Using module file /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.2.0.0_2/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/network/basics/uri.py
<cluster01> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<cluster01> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile=".vagrant/machines/cluster01/virtualbox/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/chris/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r cluster01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.66-148559593691735 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1486148016.66-148559593691735="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.66-148559593691735 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<cluster01> PUT /var/folders/g5/h48p994d3qn7d9_nz7xv2lvh0000gn/T/tmp1RWIY4 TO /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.66-148559593691735/uri.py
<cluster01> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile=".vagrant/machines/cluster01/virtualbox/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/chris/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[cluster01]'
<cluster01> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<cluster01> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile=".vagrant/machines/cluster01/virtualbox/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/chris/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r cluster01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.66-148559593691735/ /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.66-148559593691735/uri.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<cluster01> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<cluster01> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile=".vagrant/machines/cluster01/virtualbox/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/chris/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt cluster01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-qixxmffrdktqhuyukutskswbxfsaxrdd; /usr/bin/python /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.66-148559593691735/uri.py; rm -rf "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486148016.66-148559593691735/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
fatal: [cluster01]: FAILED! => {
    "cache_control": "must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store", 
    "changed": false, 
    "connection": "close", 
    "content": "<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"/>\n<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>\n</head>\n<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>\n<p>Problem accessing /pluginManager/installNecessaryPlugins. Reason:\n<pre>    No valid crumb was included in the request</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n", 
    "content_length": "387", 
    "content_type": "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", 
    "date": "Fri, 03 Feb 2017 18:53:37 GMT", 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "backup": null, 
            "body": "<jenkins><install plugin=\"git@latest\" /></jenkins>", 
            "body_format": "raw", 
            "content": null, 
            "creates": "/var/jenkins_home/plugins/git", 
            "delimiter": null, 
            "dest": null, 
            "directory_mode": null, 
            "follow": false, 
            "follow_redirects": "safe", 
            "force": false, 
            "force_basic_auth": false, 
            "group": null, 
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "text/xml", 
                "Jenkins-Crumb": "ad67abc734af7eae279df5c68098a29e"
            }, 
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget", 
            "method": "POST", 
            "mode": null, 
            "owner": null, 
            "password": "admin", 
            "regexp": null, 
            "remote_src": null, 
            "removes": null, 
            "return_content": false, 
            "selevel": null, 
            "serole": null, 
            "setype": null, 
            "seuser": null, 
            "src": null, 
            "status_code": [
                200
            ], 
            "timeout": 30, 
            "unsafe_writes": null, 
            "url": "http://cluster01:8080/pluginManager/installNecessaryPlugins", 
            "url_password": "admin", 
            "url_username": "admin", 
            "use_proxy": true, 
            "user": "admin", 
            "validate_certs": true
        }, 
        "module_name": "uri"
    }, 
    "msg": "Status code was not [200]: HTTP Error 403: No valid crumb was included in the request", 
    "redirected": false, 
    "server": "Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)", 
    "status": 403, 
    "url": "http://cluster01:8080/pluginManager/installNecessaryPlugins", 
    "x_content_type_options": "nosniff"
}
```

I've pushed the whole build (Vagrant and Ansible) to [github](https://github.com/Xetius/ci/tree/jenkins-plugin-fix-required)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this as well and found that you need to specify `force_basic_auth: True` in your `uri` task that installs the plugins.  I see that you have it in the task that registers the `crumb_token` variable (`name: Get Jenkins crumb`), so you just need to add it to the `name: Plugins are installed` task.